# Add javascript to form by module

Tags: 8, javascript, forms

i am writing a module in drupal 8. I wish to add a javascript when loading that form.

```
function ajax_example_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
 $form['#attached']['library'][] = array('ajax_example', 'ajax_example.sync_script');
}
```

and i have defined the following at the module library yml file

```
sync_script:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/test.js: {}
```

but seems the js is not embedded. And i have put the js in a folder called js at the root directory of the module.

What is the way for drupal 8 to embed a javascript at the form?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update Feb. 2023**: Hey friends! I am not writing Drupal modules for years. Please keep in mind I am not well up-to-date. This answer could not function as expected at this point in time, so edits are always welcome.

---

I don't know what you're aiming to build.

Because I think it's not good to use your JavaScript in `hook_form_alter()`, following that way, any form you try to see will invoke that JavaScript code.

However... Back to your issue. I think the `hook_form_alter()` function should be used in `module_name.module` file under the root of your module folder: `modules/custom/module_name/module_name.module` alongside the routing, info, etc.

After building the `.module` file, you need to build the `module_name.libraries.yml` file (if it's not already built), and there you write your routing requirements, for example:

```
<library_name>:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/<your_javascript_file>.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

Back to the `.module` file, you implement the `hook_form_alter`, so your code goes like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function <module_name>_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = '<module_name>/<library_name>';
    $form['#attached']['drupalSettings']['<module_name>']['<library_name>']['variable'] = 'value';
}
```

To make sure, `console.log` your PHP variable in **your_javascript_file** to see it. For example:

```
(function($){
    console.log(drupalSettings.<module_name>.<library_name>.variable); // value
})(jQuery);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please, use behaviors, see https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors

Comment: I think `route_name` would probably be better called `library_name`, since it has nothing to do with routing.

Comment: To alter only a single form, you can use implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`